# uno-check says Microsoft.NET.Workload.Mono.ToolChain.Manifest-6.0.200.6.0.2-mauipre.1.22054.8 is not signed

Tags: uno-platform

Using Visual Studio 17.1 Preview 2, after all are instaled, i run uno-check and its says:

Failed to update the advertising manifest microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain: Failed to validate package signing. Checking Microsoft.NET.Workload.Mono.ToolChain.Manifest-6.0.200.6.0.2-mauipre.1.22054.8 error: NU3004: Package is not signed. Package signature validation error.

Any Idea?

[image]
[image]
[image]